# Indexed search in postgresql takes about 200 ms (1.3M items). Is this normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I use Rails and Postgresql and have a very large table (1.3M items) called `FeededProducts` where I use this call in Rails:

```
@feed_products = FeededProduct.where("category_connection_id IN (?) AND is_available = ?", @page.category_connections.pluck(:id), true)
```

which results in the following SQL call:

```
FeededProduct Load (185.8ms)  SELECT "feeded_products".* FROM "feeded_products"  WHERE (category_connection_id IN (8,2579,3263,7791,7838) AND is_available = 't')
```

I have an index in my database:

```
  add_index "feeded_products", ["category_connection_id", "is_available", "store_id"], name: "cc_w_store_index_on_fp", using: :btree
  add_index "feeded_products", ["category_connection_id", "is_available"], name: "cc_index_on_fp", using: :btree
```

I expect this SQL to be much faster than the 150-300 ms it usually is. Is this normal? Am I missing something here that can be improved?

Edit: SQL Explain output (using eyeballs gem):

```
@feed_products = FeededProduct.where("category_connection_id IN (?) AND is_available = ?", @page.category_connections.pluck(:id), true).eyeballs.explain  
   (1.9ms)  SELECT "category_connections"."id" FROM "category_connections"  WHERE "category_connections"."page_id" = $1  [["page_id", 162]]
  FeededProduct Load (208.4ms)  SELECT "feeded_products".* FROM "feeded_products"  WHERE (category_connection_id IN (8,2579,3263,7791,7838) AND is_available = 't')
 => ["
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.feeded_products  (cost=875.39..74405.02 rows=36805 width=1085) (actual time=12.821..44.605 rows=37314 loops=1)
  Output: id, name, description, category, price, currency, in_stock, product_url, image_url, tracking_url, created_at, updated_at, store_id, slug, is_available, price_before, bad_image, category_connection_id
  Recheck Cond: (feeded_products.category_connection_id = ANY ('{8,2579,3263,7791,7838}'::integer[]))
  Filter: feeded_products.is_available
  Heap Blocks: exact=9428
  Buffers: shared hit=9545
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cc_index_on_fp  (cost=0.00..866.19 rows=36805 width=0) (actual time=10.617..10.617 rows=37314 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((feeded_products.category_connection_id = ANY ('{8,2579,3263,7791,7838}'::integer[])) AND (feeded_products.is_available = true))
        Buffers: shared hit=117
Planning time: 0.323 ms
Execution time: 47.059 ms
"]
```

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have added the explain, hope that is what you need?

Comment: The execution time is 47 ms, the query returns 37314 rows which have to be transmitted and handled by the app. This takes more time than sql execution.

Comment: Ah, ok. So the SQL index is working fine, it is more about actually handling too many resulting items. Any suggestions on how to improve this in a smart way?

Comment: Essential question - do we need such amount of data? Usually, a user is able to effectively use data of several dozen or several hundred rows. Of course, there may be special cases, generally this is a matter of good app design.

Comment: klin: Good point!